# Настройка мультиязычности

Tags: nginx

Нужно организовать поддержку 2х языков на сайте, например для русскоязычной поддержки это test.ru а для английской версии это test.ru/en

Сейчас конфиг выглядит так

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}
```

Для английской пытаюсь сделать, но не работает отдает 404

```
location /en {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /index.php?$uri&args;     
}
```

p.s Хочется сделать чтобы при выборе английской версии была подмена путей
для того чтобы не менять ссылки. например ссылка определена на русско  - язычной версии как `test.ru/about`, а на английской автоматически поменялась на `test.ru/en/about`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос это все делается без использования Nginx. Так или иначе все запросы у вас попадают в index.php.

Допустим у вас есть сайт, где все ссылки расположены в корневом каталоге. Пусть будет так about, news, index и тогда ссылки на данные страницы у вас выглядят так:

```
<a href="about">...</a>
<a href="news">...</a>
<a href="index">...</a>
```

При клике по этим ссылкам урл будет меняться на [http://site.com/выбранная_ссылка](http://site.com/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) . Надеюсь это понятно.

Теперь добавив сверху страницы новую ссылку на английский (например:

```
<a href="en/index">...</a>
```

), то при клике на нее сайт переместится в корень каталога en и теперь, при клике на всё те же ссылки которые мы приводили выше, урл будем меняться, с сохранением текущего каталога, а именно [http://site.com/en/выбранная_ссылка](http://site.com/en/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Для выхода из Английского режима ваша ссылка должна выходить в корень. Для этого вы можете сделать запись

```
<a href="../index">...</a>
```

или

```
<a href="/index">...</a>
```

Comment: Да этот бы вариант идеально подошел, но мне не хочется переписывать все ссылки, добавлять префикс, ссылок очень много + в базе еще зашито (

Comment: @itcoder Тогда вам необходимо смотреть [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), но это решение я бы никогда не поставил на "боевой" сервер и тем более не использовал бы для той задачи, которую вы описываете. Не поленитесь - сделайте как я говорю.

Comment: Да, спасибо,  наверное вы правы лучше потратить время, но сделать нормально.